# Odoo domain filter many2one

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have 3 objects:

```
class PurchaseRequest(models.Model):
    _name = 'purchase.request'

    purchase_request_line = fields.One2many('purchase.request.line', 'purchase_request_id', copy=True)
    supply_conditions_status = fields.One2many('supply.conditions', 'purchase_id', string='Order',copy=True)
```

and

```
class SupplyConditions(models.Model):
    _name = 'supply.conditions'

    name = fields.Many2one('purchase.request.line', string='Product')
```

and

```
class PurchaseRequestLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'purchase.request.line

    purchase_request_id = fields.Many2one('purchase.request', 'Purchase request')
```

Using domain I want to filter only these name field (many2one field) values which was written and saved in purchase.request form purchase_request_line field. Because now I can see all the values which was saved in database...

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_purchase_request_doc">
            <field name="name">purchase.request.doc</field>
            <field name="model">purchase.request</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Purchase Request">
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,to_approve_first,approved,rejected,canceled" statusbar_colors="{&quot;approved&quot;:&quot;green&quot;}"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>

                            <field name="purchase_request_line" attrs="{'readonly': [('state','not in', ('draft'))]}">
                                <tree string="Purchase Order Lines" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="name"/>
                                    <field name="quantity"/>
                                </tree>
                             </field>
                   <notebook>
                        <page string="Conditions" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in', ('draft', 'to_approve_first'))]}">
                            <field name="supply_conditions_status">
                                <tree string="Purchase Order Lines">
                                    <field name="name" domain="[('???', '???', '???')]"/>

                                <field name="name" options="{'no_create': True}" domain="[('name', '=', 'product_id')]"/>
```

I'll try visualize here:

[image]

I want to make that in Purchase Conditions product name many2one field I can filter and see only 2 items: item1 and item2.

Comment: i dnt understand ur question. Plz elaborate......

Comment: I updated my question, please check it

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit understand.
Can you post all of your 3 models code ?.
Or just explain a little more.

But I have a little concept to you.

So... You need to create function in *.py side.

Ex.

```
class PurchaseRequestLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'purchase.request.line

    purchase_request_id = fields.Many2one('purchase.request', 'Purchase request', domain=_getfilter)

    @api.model
    def _getfilter(self):
        return [('purchase_request_id', '=', self.env['purchase.request'].search([('name','=',???)]).name)]
```

Or another as i understand you. If you need to return the result that you want when you typing in Many2one field.

Ex.

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    args = args or []
    recs = self.browse()
    if name:
        recs = self.search(['|', ('purchase_request_id', 'ilike', name), ('name', 'ilike', name), ] + args, limit=limit)
    if not recs:
        recs = self.search(['|', ('purchase_request_id', operator, name), ('name', operator, name), ] + args, limit=limit)
    return recs.name_get()
```

Comment: I updated my question, please look at it. But as I see you understand correctly. I like the 1 example but I don't thing it is possible... I need that in supply.conditions name field (Product in form view) I can select only item1, item2 (like in picture)

Comment: on name field I need to get only these purchase.request.line values that are written in active purchase.request model. In your way I can't find active purchase.request model id